# bernoulli equations1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Solve the following bernoulli equations.

$$xy'+y=y^{-2}$$

I solving:

$$w=y^1+2$$ $$,$$

$$\frac{w'}{1+2}+1w=1$$

$$\frac{-w'}{3}=-1$$

$$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{-1}{3}w'-w)=-1$$

$$d(\frac{-1}{3}w)=-1$$

$$\frac{-1}{3}w=-1+C$$

$$= \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    w=9 & \quad \\\
    w=y^3 & \quad \  \end{array} \right.$$

I think  I got the wrong solved.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that if $x = 0$ then $y = 1$ is the solution.

Next, assume $x \neq 0$. The equation can be written as
$$y^2y' + \frac{y^3}{x} = \frac{1}{x}.$$
Put $w := y^3$ then $w' = 3y^2y'$ and the equation becomes linear:
$$\frac{w'}{3} + \frac{w}{x} = \frac{1}{x}.$$
This can be solved by separation of variables. Therefore the answer is
$$
y = \begin{cases}
1 & x = 0 \\
\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{c}{x^3}} & x \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
for some positive constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use substitution $t = \ln x$ for $x >0$ and $t= \ln (-x)$ for $x<0$. Then (for $x>0$) $$y'_x=y'_t t'_x=y'_t \frac{1}{x}$$ so $$xy'_x = y'_t$$ and our equation becomes $$y'_t+y=y^{-2}$$